# Stored procedure: Ensure that the second and subsequent procedures execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that executes several other stored procedures using `exec <SP Name>`.

How can I ensure that the second and subsequent procedures execute even if the first one fails?

Comment: Which version of MS SQL?

Comment: If the second and subsequent procedures don't rely on the first one, then change your ordering and execute the "first one" last.

Comment: side note: do what you can to make the first one not fail in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`TRY...CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) block (assuming that you're running SQL Server 2005 or newer).

```
DECLARE @failed BIT
SET @failed = 0

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC your_first_sproc
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @failed = 1
END CATCH

IF (@failed = 0)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC your_second_sproc
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @failed = 1
    END CATCH
END

IF (@failed = 0)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC your_third_sproc
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @failed = 1
    END CATCH
END

-- etc etc
```